# Store AJAX result in factory and retrieve in controller

Tags: angularjs, scope, global-variables

I am currently trying to store a $http JSON request to a variable in a factory and then retrieve the value of that variable in a controller.

Currently all I receive back is undefined. I imagine the AJAX request isn't finished running before the function gets called. I am new to Angular so trying to grab any basic concepts I can and helpful knowledge.

```
app.factory('typiCode', function($http) {
    var jsonService = {
        async: function() {
            var promise = $http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1')
            .then(function(response) {
                console.log(response);
                return response.data;
            })
            return promise;
        }  
    };
    return jsonService;
});



app.controller("getJson", function($scope, typiCode) {
    $scope.returnedData = typiCode.jsonService;
    $scope.logResults = function() {
        var theData = $scope.returnedData;
        console.log(theData);
    }
});

<button ng-click="logResults()">Launch data</button>
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `typiCode` factory returns your `jsonService` object. So you should be calling `typiCode.async()` somewhere in your code.

You could do, for example, like this in your controller:

```
app.controller("getJson", function($scope, typiCode) {

    typiCode.async()
    .then(function(data) {
        $scope.returnedData = data;
    })

    $scope.logResults = function() {
        var theData = $scope.returnedData;
        console.log(theData);
    }
});
```